# Display Excel App as first window on the screen when there is a pop up box from a running macro

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am running an excel macro from a script, I just double click on the .vbs file and it does all the work properly.

The only issue i am facing is, i have some input and messages boxes in the macro and as i am running it from the .vbs file so i don't see the excel file and if i have other windows opened like google chrome or file explorer so i have to click everytime on excel application in the taskbar to see the input box or the message box.

I should have the screen clear so that when the script is running and i have an input box it will pop up as first window.

Is there a way how to pop up this input box or message box as first window even when i have other windows opened ?
Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Your `vbscript` won't know when your `vba` macro is going to create a popup - have you considered adding `ActiveWorkbook.Activate` in the macro directly before any `MsgBox` commands?  That should cause Excel to become the active window and then the popup will be on top of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the Excel application before displaying the message. In your VBA macro code,

```
AppActivate Application.ActiveWindow.Caption
str = InputBox("Please enter a string")
MsgBox "you entered: " & str
' etc ...
```